# Which lock hints should I use (T-SQL)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concurrency, locking

I want to implement an atomic transaction like the following:

```
BEGIN TRAN A

SELECT id
FROM Inventory
WITH (???)
WHERE material_id = 25 AND quantity > 10

/*
Process some things using the inventory record and
eventually write some updates that are dependent on the fact that
that specific inventory record had sufficient quantity (greater than 10).
*/

COMMIT TRAN A
```

The problem is that there are other transactions happening that consume quantity from our inventory, so between the time that the record is selected and the updates are written in transaction A that record could become an invalid selection because it's quantity might have been lowered below the threshold in the WHERE clause.

So the question is what locking hints should I use in the WITH clause to prevent the selected inventory record from being changed before I finish my updates and commit the transaction?

EDIT:
So thanks to John, a good solution seems to be to set the transaction isolation level to REPEATABLE READ. This will will make sure that "no other transactions can modify data that has been read by the current transaction until the current transaction completes."

Comment: Good question... I'm going to be working on some code that fits exactly this criteria soon... I hadn't even realized it was an issue :)

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Yea it occurred to me that a transaction is not really producing a consistent result if the data or rather the assumptions the transaction is using are changed while it's processing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may actually be better off setting the transaction isolation level rather than using a query hint.

The following reference from Books Online provides details of each of the different Isolation levels.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Here is good article that explains the various types of locking behaviour in SQL Server and provides examples too.

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-locking-in-sql-server

Comment: So then would you suggest using REPEATABLE READ isolation level?

Comment: Yes this will certainly work. For future reference, you may wish to educate yourself regarding the other isolation levels that are available within SQL Server, that use row versioning. This is quite a tough read but valuable knowledge, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345124.aspx

Comment: Nice answer - we went through all the isolation level docs when setting up our StackOverflow DB.

Comment: The only concern I have is that setting the isolation level will effect all the transactions running in the system. Since this particular transaction will be relatively slow the transaction level will be REPEATABLE READ for a while. So other transactions that don't need really need this protection

Comment: level might start blocking, and the system will have diminished concurrency.

Comment: If significant blocking occurs in your environment then you should definately look into using a Row Versioning Isolation levels as this is an issue they are designed to address.

Comment: Hi Jarrod, so StackOverflow uses a SQL Server Backend then? I would be interested to hear about the environment.

Comment: Setting the transaction level rather than using hints does seem to be a better solution for the most part. If I run into a lot of blocking or some dead locks I'll look into Row Versioning. Thanks John.

Answer (score 2):

[table hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373(SQL.90).asp)

`WITH (HOLDLOCK)` allows other readers.
UPDLOCK as suggested elsewhere is exclusive.

HOLDLOCK will prevent other updates but they may use the data that is updated later.

UPDLOCK will prevent anyone reading the data until you commit or rollback.

Have you looked at [sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823(SQL.90).aspx)?
This would allow you to serialise this code (if it's the only update bit) without UPDLOCK blocking

Edit: The problem lies mainly in this code running in 2 different sessions.
With HOLDLOCk or REPEATABLE_READ, the data will be read in the 2nd session before the 1st session update. With UPDLOCK, noone can read the data in any session.

Comment: The problem is not trying to keep Seesion B from reading the data while Session A is executing the transaction. The problem is to keep Session B from writing to the row that Session A's transaction is using in it's calculations, to prevent the calculations from using stale data.

Comment: holdlock then. Allows read but not write.

Or load all data into local vars/table variables

Answer (score 2):

MSSQL:

```
SELECT id
FROM Inventory (UPDLOCK)
WHERE material_id = 25 AND quantity > 10;

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13134
```

---

By any chance you're interested with PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT id
FROM Inventory    
WHERE material_id = 25 AND quantity > 10
FOR UPDATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be UPDLOCK.

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13134

Comment: Keep in mind that locking does not behaive this way in SQL Server 2005 and above. The article is quite dated.

Answer (score 0):

Lock hints:

```
WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
```

Comment: to make sure that no other process can even read this and it will hold it for the duration of the tran

Comment: do updlock then open another window and do a select against the same table

Comment: doh! of course. an update lock is not an exclusive lock.
Not sure it's needed though... it depends how you read the problem