# CURSOR is not working for DECLARED table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In my sql code I have declared a table(A) and inserting some rows to that table from a database table(B). Then I have to take those inserted rows from A and put it into a CURSOR and after I do a `FETCH NEXT` still the `@@FETCH_STATUS` is `-1`. But the expected value for the `@@FETCH_STATUS` is `0`.
I am putting a simplified code below the question.

Can I know what is the wrong with this code. Can I use declared tables to populate the `CURSOR`s in SQL or cursor has to be populated from a created table in the database.

```
// This is a code that goes inside a Stored Procedure.

AS
   DECLARE A TABLE (.........)// A table has same fields in table B
   DECLARE s INT

   WHILE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM B WHERE ......)
   BEGIN
      BEGIN TRAN
      INSERT INTO A SELECT TOP 10 (....)FROM B WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) WHERE ....

      SELECT s = count(*) from A // this returns some value which means inserting is working 
      DECLARE  dataSet CURSOR FOR (SELECT..... FROM A)
      OPEN dataSet
      FETCH NEXT FROM dataSet INTO ...

       WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 // coming value for this is -1
       BEGIN
          //Code goes here
          FETCH NEXT FROM dataSet INTO ...
        END

   CLOSE dataSet
   DEALLOCATE dataSet
   DELETE FROM A
   COMMIT TRAN
END
```

Comment: You've not shown enough - if I take your example and fix the obvious bugs (e.g. prefix non-cursor variables with `@`), then it runs fine for me (of course, I've also had to make up a table definition and sample data). Could you try fixing your example to one that actually exhibits the problem (and that other people have a chance of being able to run for themselves)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ill add my whole code

Comment: Another thing, Sorry About the mistake @ I missed that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a runnable version of the OPs question - but it doesn't exhibit the issue. This isn't an answer, so CW, and I'll delete if/when the OP does post an actual example:

```
create table B (ID int not null,Val1 varchar(10) not null)
go
insert into B(ID,Val1) values (1,'abc'),(2,'ade')
go
create procedure DoStuff
AS
   DECLARE @A TABLE (ID int not null,Val1 varchar(10) not null)
   DECLARE @s INT

   WHILE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM B WHERE Val1 like 'a%')
   BEGIN
      BEGIN TRAN
      INSERT INTO @A SELECT TOP 10 ID,Val1 FROM B WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) WHERE Val1 like 'a%'

      SELECT @s = count(*) from @A
      DECLARE dataSet CURSOR FOR (SELECT ID,Val1 FROM @A)
      declare @ID int
      declare @Val1 varchar(10)
      OPEN dataSet
      FETCH NEXT FROM dataSet INTO @ID,@Val1

       WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN
          RAISERROR('%i: %s',10,1,@ID,@Val1) WITH NOWAIT
          UPDATE B set Val1 = 'done' where ID = @ID
          FETCH NEXT FROM dataSet INTO @ID,@Val1
        END

   CLOSE dataSet
   DEALLOCATE dataSet
   DELETE FROM @A
   COMMIT TRAN
END
GO
EXEC DoStuff
GO
SELECT * from B
```

Output:

```
(2 row(s) affected)

(2 row(s) affected)
1: abc

(1 row(s) affected)
2: ade

(1 row(s) affected)

(2 row(s) affected)

(2 row(s) affected)
```

and table `B`:

```
ID  Val1
1   done
2   done
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I will post the actual scenario of the issue as soon as possible. So it seems the same code is working properly in yours.

Answer (score 1):

Since its uncommited transaction on table A, table A might have been locked. So for your dataset cursor try-

```
select '' from A with (nolock) where ...
```

Comment: Good point, I will edit the code again. I have included another set of locks for the purpose as explained here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1524803/892788). I am using `UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK`in my code. And I tried your code. But problem exists the same.

Comment: But I get your point now. It has to do something abut this committing.

Answer (score 1):

i think create temp table then declare it for cursor, not must be have an existing table
like:

```
DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR SELECT id INTO temp_table FROM user_id
```