# Stored Procedure Transactions

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a ticketing system where I need to hand out unique numbers always handing out the lowest available number. Here is the "Ticket" table:

- Id - PK, int
- OtherId - int, nullable

The ticket table contains 100 available numbers.

I have a stored procedure with the following code in it:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET @value = (SELECT MIN(Id) FROM Screens WHERE OtherId IS NULL)
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:15'; --Only here for testing purposes
UPDATE 
    Screens
SET 
    OtherId = @OthererId 
WHERE
    Screens.Number = @value
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Transactions don't seem to be doing what I had hoped. With the delay, I can run the procedure twice and the second returns the same value as the first. I want to ensure that each value is unique. How do I accomplish thie.

Comment: Why always the lowest? Do the ticket numbers get re used?

Comment: @value always is NULL, since SELECT MIN(OtherId) FROM Screens WHERE OtherId IS NULL

Comment: This is very strange. Why always a unique number, but only 100 values? That will run out very quick.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you should look into HOLDLOCK + UPDLOCK, maybe this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524155/what-effect-does-holdlock-have-on-updlock

Comment: Very close. I found TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK worked.

Comment: Thanks, Wendy. I cleaned up and simplified my code and put in the wrong variable name. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the first line after "Begin Transaction" to

```
SET @value = (SELECT MIN(Id) FROM Screens  WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK) WHERE OtherId IS NULL)
```