# Deadlock with single stored procedure and multiple threads

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, multithreading, stored-procedures

I'm running some tests on SQL transactions in multithreaded environment. I am trying to generate deadlock by executing single stored procedure in a loop from 2 threads running in paralel. Both of my threads use the same method on start, which continuously executes a single stored procedure:

```
using (TestDataContext db = new TestDataContext())
{
    while (true)
    {
        db.DeadLocking();
    }
}
```

Can someone give an example of "DeadLocking" stored procedure that would reliably generate deadlock in this case senario. It must use transactions (single or multiple). I've researched for quite a bit and saw many examples of how to generate deadlocks in sql, however, none of them worked in my code. Please, help.

Update: Following Marc's suggestions I tried this sproc to no avail:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeadLocking]
AS
BEGIN
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
SET NOCOUNT ON
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            DECLARE @val varchar(1)
            SELECT @val = Record FROM Test.dbo.Records WHERE RecordId = 1
            UPDATE Test.dbo.Records SET Record = @val WHERE RecordId = 1
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Running it from both threads in paralel supposed to lock those threads on eachother. What am I doing wrong?

Update: The above procedure does cause deadlock, however, it takes at least 3 threads to do this not 2 (no idea why, maybe it takes 2 but also takes forever). Funny thing is that this also causes deadlock:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeadLocking]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
    UPDATE Test.dbo.Records SET Record = 1 WHERE RecordId = 1
END
```

I'm guessing that happens because stored procedure itself implements some sort of transaction logic behind the scene. If anyone has more info on why it happens, please share. 
Mind you, the deadlock happens only on UPDATE and doesn't happen on SELECT. This occurs on both SERIALIZABLE and REPEATABLE READ isolation levels.

Comment: Classic way to deadlock: using "serializable" isolation level, have spid A take a read-lock on some data (without `updlock`); have spid B take a read lock on *the same data*; now how spid A take a write lock on that same data (try to change a column), and have spid B try to do the same. They are now both deadlocked on eachother.

Comment: @Marc, I don't suppose simple SELECT would get a read-lock on a row, would it?

Comment: In serializable isolation level; yes: it would. In most other isolation levels: no

Comment: Re your edit: this is a *thread race* scenario - unless you manually orchestrate it from the outside, it is entirely possible that you'd never see the conflict here, unless you iterate it many many thousands of times. One thing you could do to help force it is add a `WAITFOR` delay (maybe 5 seconds) between the `SELECT` and `UPDATE`, so that there's a much higher chance that both SPIDs will have the read lock before either tries to do the update.

Comment: No need for the passive-aggressive posturing there

Answer (score 0):

Consider asking for update locks in the select. WITH (UPDLOCK).

That makes sure that the SELECT already will update the record.

Comment: " I am trying to generate deadlock " - this would seem to be the exact *opposite* of useful, in terms of achieving that aim

Answer (score 0):

To create a deadlock, you will definitely need *two* different procedures, or at least branches of execution, which acquire locks in different order.

In fact, ensuring a strict order on acquiring locks is a well-known means to *prevent* deadlocks.

So you will need *two* different locks A and B, for example on two different tables. Then one thread will try to lock A *then* B, while the other thread will try to lock B *then* A. Only this way there's the chance to create a deadlock.

If you want to increase the probability of a deadlock actually occurring at runtime, some delay will be needed, like:

```
lock A
delay5Seconds
lock B
delay5Seconds
unlock B
unlock A
```

and

```
lock B
delay5Seconds
lock A
delay5Seconds
unlock A
unlock B
```

This allows the other thread to hit the right point in time to deadlock.

To make this deterministically generate a deadlock every time, one would have to create a mechanism to synchronize both thread executions, like

```
lock A
wait for thread #2 to lock B
lock B
...
```

and

```
lock B
wait for thread #1 to lock A
lock A
...
```

EDIT:

Found this SO question which seems to be related: [Confused about UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843733/confused-about-updlock-holdlock)

Extrapolating from that you might try it like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT * FROM Test.dbo.Records WHERE RecordId = 1 WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
SELECT * FROM Test.dbo.Records WHERE RecordId = 999999 WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

and

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT * FROM Test.dbo.Records WHERE RecordId = 999999 WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
SELECT * FROM Test.dbo.Records WHERE RecordId = 1 WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

This, in principle, should do the trick on all transaction isolation levels. (You're using *explicit* locks in both threads, so it would be bold for the DBMS to ignore that.)
However, I'm not at all certain if the two consecutive selects from the same table will actually acquire two separate locks (one on each affected record), or if the DBMS might just decide to lock the whole table, or at least a single range of it, so that only one lock is effectively held. Hence, to be sure you actually get two locks at different points in time, you may actually want to spread the two selects to two different tables.

Comment: I think it should, if you use the right kind of locks. TomTom's suggestion about `WITH (UPDLOCK)` for explicit *write* locking sounds promising. If, on the other hand, you want to create a deadlock situation with a combination of read and write locks the result will be likely to depend on the isolation level.

Comment: Yeah, mate, this will generate deadlocks, however, it uses UPDLOCK which explicitly establishes required locks and uses 2 diffenent transactions that lock on eachother, which is a bit different from what my question is asking. But thanks for additional info.