# Many updates get deadlock error

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

Use node.js + sequelize.js + mssql

I do many updates ~30 (one table) from 3 threads every 5 seconds. Device polling.

Get

> SequelizeDatabaseError:  Transaction (Process ID 57) was deadlocked on
>   lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the
>   deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

sequelize generate sql

```
sql: 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [DeviceCurrentData] ON;

MERGE INTO [DeviceCurrentData] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS [DeviceCurrentData_target]
USING (
    VALUES (
        9,
        N\ '28.300000\',
        \ '2017-08-07 15:26:28.000\',
        12
        )
    ) AS [DeviceCurrentData_source]([Id], [Value], [DateStamp], [DevParamId])
    ON [DeviceCurrentData_target].[Id] = [DeviceCurrentData_source].[Id]
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
        UPDATE
        SET [DeviceCurrentData_target].[Value] = N\ '28.300000\',
            [DeviceCurrentData_target].[DateStamp] = \ '2017-08-07 15:26:28.000\',
            [DeviceCurrentData_target].[DevParamId] = 12
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN
        INSERT (
            [Id],
            [Value],
            [DateStamp],
            [DevParamId]
            )
        VALUES (
            9,
            N\ '28.300000\',
            \ '2017-08-07 15:26:28.000\',
            12
            )
OUTPUT $ACTION,
    INSERTED.*;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [DeviceCurrentData] OFF;
```

'

Comment: [This previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843733/confused-about-updlock-holdlock) might help. Your use of `HOLDLOCK` would block both `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, whereas using `UPDLOCK` would only block the `UPDATE`. You should trace that spid and find whether it was an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` that failed.

Comment: I write `Model.update(item, {Id: item.Id})`, but sequelize.js geneterate `HOLDLOCK`. I wrote `Model.upsert` , also get deadlock error

Answer (score 0):

HOLDLOCK is a table level lock.  Once it is issued, any other transactions are prevented from modify the table contents until the HOLDLOCK transaction completes.  MERGE is not good for concurrency as it has multiple phases in which other transactions can get stuck..

For high concurrency, you should probably use an upsert.  (Try an update, if the output is null, do an insert).

Also, the update is best targeted against a single row at a time, using the full clustered index key.  If you're trying to update multiple rows or your filter is not covered by the index, it can escalate into a larger lock and cause deadlocks as well.

Mitigating deadlocks is a complicated topic.  Good luck.

Comment: Model.upsert also get deadlock error.  Header with HOLDLOCK  generate automatically, may I change it?
When I work with C# and EntityFramework, I haven't this error

Comment: Yes, you can remove the hold lock.  You should not need to add a lock at all for this simple transaction, assuming ID is your primary key field.  Another option is a delete/insert.  Rather than updating the record, delete it then insert it new.