# SQL Server : Update by Batch Or Lock Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am issuing an UPDATE statement to a list of records in bulk.

There's a trigger in the database table to start firing whenever detect a change of value.

Is there a way for me to hold all the update and complete then release for reading ?

Saw many options here but getting confuse ...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver15

My SQL Command

```
 UPDATE tbl_table1 SET colStatus = 'Y' WHERE zDate > GETDATE()-1
```

There could be 10 records, 100 or 1000 or 100,000 records that need to be updated. I know it is fast but I just want to make all records to have same status then allow for reading.

Any thoughts ? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to "hold all the update and complete then release for reading" for your trigger? If `UPDATE tbl_table1 SET colStatus = 'Y' WHERE zDate > GETDATE()-1` updates 1000 records, then the `inserted` table in your trigger will hold 1000 records. It's up to the trigger logic to decide what it does with that.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to hold all records then release. I totally agree with you it is up to the trigger logic how they read that. Also, it is up to the UPDATE statement which record to update first. Although I would like to use an ORDER BY to update it based on the date/time. But UPDATE using ORDER BY not supported unless, I use a CURSOR to loop through each record then update. It is just not efficient

Comment: The order doesn't matter, that's why it isn't supported. It either updates _all_ 1000 records, _or_ if there is an issue, it rolls it all back and doesn't update any _records_ The question and your explanation indicates there is some kind of misunderstanding about how update works. I still don't understand what you mean by "hold all the update and complete then release for reading", but possibly.... that is the way it already works. If you have a single update or insert or delete, statement, either all the records are affected, or there is no change at all.

Comment: Maybe you want `HOLDLOCK` but TBH I only ever see locking hints when the developer doesn't understand locking properly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843733/confused-about-updlock-holdlock

Comment: i totally agree with your statement but i just need to do some research to explore my other options such as hold up / lock everything then release. thanks...

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: This smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - in particular, a problem with a trigger that perhaps does not properly support multirow operations.

Comment: What does "hold all the update and complete then release for reading" mean, or what do you think it means? And how do you think updates and triggers actually work? There's clearly some kind of misunderstanding here but can't put my finger on what exactly