# Getting available codes by given amount using information from a second table

Tags: sql

I have `Codes` table with unique codes that can have the same `type`, and `Usage` table that holds information about the usage of the codes, and it can hold multiple rows with the same code, for example:

`AvailableCodes` table:

| id | code | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa1 | type_1 |
| 2 | bb1 | type_2 |
| 3 | cc1 | type_3 |
| 4 | cc2 | type_3 |
| 5 | bb2 | type_2 |
| 6 | bb3 | type_2 |
| 7 | cc3 | type_3 |
| 8 | cc4 | type_3 |
| 9 | aa2 | type_1 |
| 10 | aa3 | type_1 |

`Usage` table:

| code | some_information1 | some_information2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa1 | some_info1 | some_info2 |
| cc2 | some_info1 | some_info2 |
| cc2 | some_info1 | some_info2 |
| bb1 | some_info1 | some_info2 |
| aa1 | some_info1 | some_info2 |

Given an array that holds type and number for each type, how can I get list of unique codes that are not present in the `Usage` table according to that number of each type?

For example if I get:

```
[
  type_1: 2,
  type_3: 1
]
```

Then I want the result to have 2 codes of `type_1`, and 1 result from `type_3`, that can be fetched by `id ASC` order (or any other order):

Expected result:

| code | type |
| --- | --- |
| aa2 | type_1 |
| aa3 | type_1 |
| cc1 | type_2 |

But if there aren't enough codes available return empty set:

```
[
  type_1: 3,
  type_3: 1
]
```

returns empty because only 2 `type_1` are available (`aa1` is in `Usage` table).

Comment: I think your example may be wrong? Should the first table contain type_3 for code cc1?

Comment: Yes it's the code value of type_3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do a left join to get the list of codes that are not present in the `Usage` table, use a conditional count window function to check the count of that codes for each required type, and use the row_number function to get rows according to your predefined limit. Putting all together, you may try the following:

```
SELECT code, type
FROM
(
  SELECT avc.code, avc.type,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN avc.type = 'type_1' THEN 1 END) OVER () cn1,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN avc.type = 'type_3' THEN 1 END) OVER () cn2,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY avc.type ORDER BY avc.id) rn
  FROM  AvailableCodes avc left JOIN Usage usg
  ON usg.code = avc.code
  WHERE usg.code IS NULL
) t
WHERE (cn1 >= 2 AND cn2 >= 1) AND
      ((type = 'type_1' AND rn <= 2) OR (type = 'type_3' AND rn <= 1))
ORDER BY type, code
```

[See a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/KyOU1YB3)

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. Do you know if I can also lock the selected rows from `AvailableCodes` so that no one will select the chosen codes simultaneously? I'm not sure where to put the `with(rowlock, updlock, holdlock)` on such complex query in a way that it will only lock the selected codes but let other users select other codes. Also not sure if I need all the locks (`rowlock, updlock, holdlock`)

Comment: Well, the syntax is to put the `with hint` clause on each table you wish to lock, [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/5dWdp0gA)

Comment: What hints to use, it is depending on what you are trying to do, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843733/confused-about-updlock-holdlock) may help you. You may also ask another question clarifying why you want to lock the selected rows.

Comment: Thank you, I actually made a question and there are answers on it already but I might have confused the people who answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75785332/how-to-lock-the-selected-rows-in-this-query-with-sub-query/75790692#75790692. Basically I need to insert the codes returned from the above array into the `Usage` table and make sure the same code isn't used more than once. For that I might add a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause as seen in the answer in my other question?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to reply to you, anyway I checked the answer there and I have nothing to add. Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you. Btw I think you are correct and not the answer in the other answer. In your example you put hints twice: on `avc` and `usage` whereas the other answer only put it on `usage` but that might still create duplicates so I'll use your example with both locks

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct code, type 
from AvailableCodes 
where code not in (select distinct code from Usage)
order by id asc;
```

Comment: This won't solve for his return empty example.