# sql server - locking existing records in a transaction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions

I have a stored procedure that takes an xml parameter.  For simplicity sake lets say the xml represents a collection of cars.  Each element in the collection represents a car and has details such as an identification number and Manufacturer.  The goal of the stored procedure is to insert the data in the database.  The database schema is normalized so there is a table for Manufacturer, and a table for Cars.  Many cars can have the same manufacturer.

The schema looks like this:
[image]

In processing the xml I need to insert manufactures listed in the xml that aren't in the database, then insert cars listed in the xml that aren't in the database.

1. Insert unique Manufacturers from the xml into the Manufactures table
2. Insert records into the cars table from the xml, joining to the manufacture table on the manufacturer name, to get the appropriate manufacturer ID.

Between step 1 and 2 it might be possible for a user or some other process to delete manufacture records, so that even though I inserted manufacture records, or one already existed that I needed, by the time I get to inserting car records the required manufacture record no longer exists.

How can I prevent this?  I can do this all in a transaction which would lock manufacturer records I insert until the commit, but how can I lock records I need that already existed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497049/which-lock-hints-should-i-use-t-sql
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-locking-in-sql-server

Comment: Put both inserts inside a transaction. Problem solved.

Comment: Introducing lock is not a simple decision. If you don't expect a lot of conflicts, you can always check the result of your second insertion and roll back your first one if the second one fails.  You may have to do it again but it's better than dead locks and other overheads introduced by locks.

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple if you use a sql transaction.

Pseudocode:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT Manufacturers

INSERT Cars

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Nothing can delete the Manufacturers row(s) inserted from this process until your transaction is complete (committed or rolled back).

Comment: Yes but if the manufacture table already has a record in it, I won't be inserting, so the record won't be locked.  I need to insert into cars, and I'll be referencing the existing manufacturer record.